# How to propagate parent click state to its child

Tags: android

I have a layout like this, which is used as a ListView Item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  
    android:id="@+id/parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/child"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_here" >

        <ImageView />

        <ImageView />

        <TextView />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have a selector to the only child which is in the parent(the actual Item). I have implemented the `onItemClickListener` but the selector doesn't work because its added to the child instead of the parent.

How can I propagate this click to the child, so that it's selector works.

When I search for a solution, all I found is:

`android:addStatesFromChildren="true"`

which says

> The children's state is propagated to the parent

But I want the reverse of it.

Thank You

Comment: Did you try this? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:duplicateParentState

Comment: Yeah I tried adding that to the `@+id/child` view. But didn't work.